# QT project error: Unknown module in QT: widget

Tags: c++, qt

I installed the Qwt library (osx) and added it to my Qt project. After executing:

```
qmake -set QMAKEFEATURES ${QWT_ROOT}/features
```

I got the project build error:

```
QT project error: Unknown module in QT: widget
```

I removed the Qwt library from my project and system but the error is still existing. I also tried to reinstall Qt 5.2.1 and removed all user settings but still the same problem. To check if the property is still there I executed:

```
qmake -query QMAKEFEATURES
```

which returned:

```
**Unknown**
```

therefore this should not be the problem.

The compiler gives the following output:

```
ASSERT: "fileName.isEmpty() || isAbsolutePath(fileName)" in file /work/build/qt5_workdir/w/s/qtbase/qmake/library/ioutils.cpp, line 61
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out there is a bug report in QT:
[https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29642?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-29642?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel)

As I entered the command:

```
qmake -query
```

without an argument, it output that the property QMAKEFEATURES was still set:

```
QMAKEFEATURES:/usr/local/qwt-6.1.1-svn/features
```

Finally invoking:

```
qmake -unset QMAKEFEATURES
```

solved the problem.